# How to cancel a specific POST request through AFNetworking?

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
[manager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

As this is code is not working. Please help me with an optimize solution.

Comment: Of course that is not working, you are create an new instance of the operation manager. Just call `cancelAllOperations` on the instance of the operation manager which is performing the request or cancel the request it self.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not using AFHTTPRequestOperation. And cancelAllOperation cant call by manager. So how can I create instance of AFHTTPRequestOperation while using AFHTTPRequestOperationManager